# Calculate Account Receivables using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to calculate account receivable using LINQ.

I have tried this but stuck here.
I have done this in SQL but I want this in LINQ so I can use it in my MVC project.

```
var sale = saleslist.GroupBy(s => s.BuyerId).Select(s => s.Sum(u => u.Amount)).ToList();
var receipt = receiptslist.GroupBy(r => r.StakeHolderId).Select(t => t.Sum(u => u.Amount)).ToList();

List<AccountReceivablesVM> res = db.StakeHolders
    .Where(r=>r.StakeHolderTypeId == "0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10")
    .Select(rvm => new AccountReceivablesVM
    {
        CompanyName = rvm.CompanyName,
        Receivables = //don't know what to do here
    }).ToList();
```

**Models:**

```
public class StakeHolder
{
    public string StakeHolderId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string StakeHolderTypeId { get; set; }
}


public class Sale
{
    public string SaleId { get; set; }
    public string RefNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string BuyerId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
}


public class PaymentsAndReceipt
{
    public string PaymentAndReceiptId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> VoucherNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string StakeHolderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
}

public class AccountReceivablesVM
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Receivables { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Comment: You've described `PaymentsAndReceipt` twice, but forgot to give us `StakeHolders` and `Sales`. Does every `StakeHolder`have zero or more `AccountsReceivablesVM` (one-to-many)? Do you want the total `Receivables` per stakeholder in your end result?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Thanks for pointing mistake, yes I want to calculate total receivables per stakeholder in end result.

Comment: Can you post some input data also

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Question Updated.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. It is still not correct: Sales don't have a CompanyName. Furthermore I'm missing the relations between the tables. Does a StakeHolder have zero or more Sales? And what is the relation between Stakeholders and AccountReceivablesVM? One-to-many? Why are you not using foreign keys to implement these relations? You'll get into trouble if two companies have the same name, or if "British Telecom" changes its name to "BT"

Comment: Sir, the screenshots showing the result, I'm getting CompanyName in Sales by BuyerId which is ForeignKey of StakeHolderId. secondly yes, A StakeHolder have zero or many Sales. Third AccountReceivablesVM is a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can join first with stakeholderId and then sum the amount and then group by with company name and stakeholder id, however I write the code in Linq. I have considered the stakeholderid as the primary key of your table just because you have not mentioned the schema of stakeholder so.

```
        var result = from s in db.StakeHolders 
                    join pr in db.PaymentsAndReceipt on s.StakeHolderId equals pr.StakeHolderId
                    where StakeHolderTypeId == "0b85a69e-55f2-4142-a49d-98e22aa7ca10"
                    group s by new { s.StakeHolderId,s.CompanyName} into p
                    select new
                    {
                      StakeHolderId= p.Key.StakeHolderId,
                      CompanyName= p.Key.CompanyName, 
                      Receivables = string.Format("{0:C}", p.Sum(y => y.Amount))
                   };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, but I need to calculate customers receivables not only their receipts total.